# How to enter login credentials on form using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm having difficulty sending login credentials to a form by selecting the 'class' elements. I get the 'Unable to locate element' error when running the code below. Not sure what to look for in the HTML code

'''

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\aigag\Documents\Python Projects\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get("https://www.goodlifefitness.com/home.html")

login = driver.find_element_by_class_name("c-header__login-text")
login.click()
time.sleep(1)

driver.switch_to_frame('destination_publishing_iframe_goodlifefitness_0')

loginemail = driver.find_element_by_class_name('c-field__input js-login-email c-login-block__input')
loginpass = driver.find_element_by_class_name("c-field__input js-login-password c-login-block__input")
time.sleep(2)

loginemail.send_keys('@gmail.com')

time.sleep(5)
driver.close()
```

'''

HTML code
'''

```
<input type="email" placeholder="Enter Member ID, barcode or email address" class="c-field__input js-login-email c-login-block__input">
```

'''

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace spaces with dots. As well as add webdriver waits for page loading and remove time.sleep(). As well as removing the iframe since it wasn't inside.

```
driver.get("https://www.goodlifefitness.com/home.html")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
login = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "c-header__login-text")))
login.click()
loginemail = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "c-field__input.js-login-email.c-login-block__input")))
loginpass = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CLASS_NAME, "c-field__input.js-login-password.c-login-block__input")))
loginemail.send_keys('@gmail.com')
```

Import

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait 
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access an element with more than one class name, put a period, not a space, between the class names.
For example:

`loginemail = browser.find_element_by_class_name('c-field__input.js-login-email.c-login-block__input')`